Unable to style Cue in default SubtitleView Media3 ExoPlayer
I am trying to style captions that come into my DASH segment as .vtt files. Scouted the internet for how to do that, and found a suggestion from the ExoPlayer devs here
Moving further with the suggestion of styling Cue objects, I couldn't get it to work.
Here's a sample code for reference
The params zoomInFactor, subtitleTopSpacing , subtitleFontSize are all part of business logic, and can vary
Also the flag isVideoZoomed, is also business logic, and the spacing can vary
Here, I am concerned about the fact, that these styled Cues are not being applied to the subtitleView using subtitleView?.setCues(cues)
What can be doing wrong?
fun setCues(
        cues: ImmutableList<Cue>,
        zoomInFactor: Float,
        subtitleTopSpacing: Float,
        subtitleFontSize: Float,
){

 if (cues.isEmpty()) return
        // First clear the existing cues
        subtitleView?.setCues(null)
        try {
            // Modify the existing cues as per the available parameters
            val modifiedCues = cues.map { cue ->
                val cueBuilder = cue.buildUpon()
                if (isVideoZoomed) {
                    cueBuilder.setLine(
                        (subtitleTopSpacing + ((zoomInFactor - 1) * 0.5F)) / zoomInFactor,
                        Cue.LINE_TYPE_FRACTION,
                    )
                    cueBuilder.setTextSize(
                        subtitleFontSize / zoomInFactor,
                        Cue.TEXT_SIZE_TYPE_FRACTIONAL,
                    )
                } else {
                    cueBuilder.setLine(subtitleTopSpacing, Cue.LINE_TYPE_FRACTION)
                    cueBuilder.setTextSize(
                        subtitleFontSize, Cue.TEXT_SIZE_TYPE_FRACTIONAL,
                    )
                }
                cueBuilder.lineAnchor = Cue.ANCHOR_TYPE_END
                cueBuilder.build()
            }
            subtitleView?.setCues(modifiedCues)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
}


